# array incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

can anyone please let me know what's the difference b/w

```
int vector[]={10,20,30}
int *p = vector
```

and

```
int *p= &vector
```

I know by mentioning array name, we get it's base address . The second statement is giving me warning

initialisation from incompatible pointer type

Why warning, both  statement give array base address.

Answer (score 4):

When used in an expression, an array name will in most cases *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

So this:

```
int *p = vector;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int *p = &vector[0];
```

The type of `&vector[0]` is `int *`, so the type is compatible.

One of the few times an array does *not* decay is when it is the object of the address-of operator `&`.  Then `&array` is the address of the array and has type `int (*)[3]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 3.  This is not compatible with `int *`, hence the error.

Although the address of the array and the address of its first element have the same *value*, their *types* are different.

Answer (score 2):

`&vector` is of type `int (*)[3]` i.e. a *pointer* to an array, whereas `vector` without `&` would decay to `int *` pointing to the first element.

`int (*)[3]`, even though pointing at the same *address* is incompatible with `int *`, hence your program has a constraint violation, which makes your program an *invalid* program, and a compiler must issue a diagnostics message.

The C standard explicitly mentions in a [footnote ([C11 footnote 9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note9)) that a compiler is allowed to successfully compile an invalid program:

> 9) The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. **It may also successfully translate an invalid program.**

I.e. a compiler is allowed to do whatever it pleases with the given source, provided that a **valid program is correctly translated**. Hence many compilers will look these kinds of things through the fingers with default settings and provide a translation that has more or less expected - or equally unexpected - results, and you will get ***only* a warning**.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions in C have both *values* and *types*.

Given `int vector[] = {10, 20, 30};`, `vector` is an array. C has a rule that, when an array is used in an expression outside of certain places<sup>1</sup>, it is automatically converted to be a pointer to its first element. Then its value is effectively the address of the start of the array<sup>2</sup>, and its type is “pointer to `int`”.

The expression `&vector` takes the address of the array. This is different from the address of its first element. Largely, they both have the same *value*. Both the array and its first element start at the same place in memory. But they have different *types*. The type of `&vector` is “pointer to array of 3 `int`”.

C has rules about types, and you cannot automatically use one type where another is expected. Sometimes types are converted automatically, as when a narrower integer is converted to a wider integer. But, generally in places where the type is important to the meaning of the software, there are no automatic conversions (or limited conversions). If you try to assign a pointer to an array to a pointer to an `int`, a good compiler will warn you you are doing something improper.

When a pointer to one type is assigned to a pointer to a different type, it might be because the programmer has made a mistake. This is why the compiler warns you.

Additionally, the same value with different types may behave differently. Because `array` is a pointer to its first *element*, `a + 1` is a pointer to the second element. But, since `&array` is a pointer to the *array*, `&array + 1` is a pointer to the end of the array (where the next array after it would start, if there were one).

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> An array is not automatically converted when it is the operand of `sizeof` or the operand of unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

<sup>2</sup> The array starts in the same place in memory that its first element starts, of course. So they have the same virtual address. So they have the same value in that sense. However, there are some technical issues about C pointers that mean two pointers to the same place may not be exactly the “same” in certain senses. In this answer, I will not get into details of that. We can treat pointers to the same place as the same in this discussion.

Comment: not "a good compiler" - a compiler that doesn't warn is not a C compiler by definition.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It is a compiler nonetheless. Most compilers are not C compilers.

Comment: @P.P.: C 2018 6.5.16.1 specifies constraints for assignment that are violated by assigning a pointer to an array to a pointer to an `int`. C 2018 5.1.1.3 requires a conforming implementation to produce a diagnostic if a constraint is violated. Therefore, software that does not produce such a diagnostic is not a conforming implementation of the C standard.

Comment: Of course GCC is (close to) a C compiler only with `-pedantic` as in the other recent question it doesn't produce any diagnostics when comparing `double *` against `0` with an inequality operator :(

Comment: @P.P.: Which is what Antti Haapala’s comment said, if a compiler is not producing a diagnostic, it is not a **C compiler**.